# FullCalendar's events function

Tags: jquery, events, fullcalendar, asp.net-1.1

I'm using Fullcalendar in my Asp.Net 1.1 application. For taking data from server side, I use Ajaxpro. So codes to gets events to Fullcalendar are written as below:

```
    $calendar.fullCalendar({        
        editable: true,
        selectable: true,
        theme: true,
        height: 545,                
        defaultView: 'agendaWeek',
        header: {
                left: 'prev,next today',
                center: 'title',
                right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
            },
        events: function(start, end, callback) {
            dss.user_activity.getActivities(function(doc) {
            var events = [];
                        var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(doc.value);
                        $(obj.Head).each(function() {                           
                            events.push({
                id: this.SQ_USER_ACTIVITY_ID,
                            title: this.CH_SUBJECT,
                            start: this.start, 
                end:   this.end,
                allDay: this.BL_ALL_DAY             
                            });
                        }); 
                      callback(events);
            });
            }
});
```

But I have a problem that, When I drag an events which came from database and switch Calendar's view, all events go back to their default location.

I want changed events to protect their location, when I swtich the Calendar view.

Answer (score 1):

You need to save events to the database, then.  Use a callback on the drop event for your event to save it to the database.  When  you switch views, it refreshes the events by calling the database.

Comment: Thanks for you reply. Saving events to database for every change event is not a useful way. I lastly click a save button to save them all.

Comment: Then I'd check on a way to keep it from going to the server to fetch events it already has when you change the view.  What is happening right now is default behavior.

Comment: What exactly is happening that, events function trigered in every switching and dss.user_activity.getActivities function is running. Normally if I write only server-side code I could get rid of this issue with page.ispostback method. But in client-side I don't know how to do a behaviour like ispostback control.

Comment: You need to look at the Javascript events called in fullcalendar to find the answer to your question.